# Any way to add a project photo to open source project in Developer Story?

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I want to add 3 of my open source projects to my **Developer Story**. I noticed there are 2 options that make sense for this thing:

1. Feature or Apps
2. Open source

**Feature or Apps** projects have a "feature or app" title, and ***the user can set the avatar***.

**Open Source** projects have the "open source" mini title, and a github avatar.

I feel like the change is too un-noticed and especially the fact that **Open Source** is lacking an avatar gives it a disadvantage.

maybe highlight better what's open source by a github's mini-icon next to the project's avatar?

I would love it if in a glance you could distinguish between apps and open source apps (and both with avatars for awesomeness :-))

Also, I thought that apps and open source projects can be related to organizations and positions. is there anything that can connect them in the ui? maybe have some sort of overlap in the timeline for positions and apps\open-source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback! This avatar inconsistency is definitely on our radar and we plan to work on it soon :). We'll also look into your recommendation on overlapping story items.

Comment: Great to hear! I agree it would be nice to be able to use a custom image and not just the GitHub logo :)